# Flash ActionScript 3.0 KeysUp & KeysDown method error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Have the following code for Game Show Software which:

1. Allows a user to press a button and it switches to the particular frame.
2. SpaceBar is set up as the "reset button" taking the user back to the original frame 1.

Current issue: SpaceBar instead takes user back to whatever the previous frame was (be it frame 2, 3 or 432). But pressing SpaceBar twice reverts back to frame 1.

Cannot figure out why.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keysUp);
var value:Number;

function keysUp(event:KeyboardEvent){

 if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
  gotoAndStop(1);
 }
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
  gotoAndStop(4);
  stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.Z) {
  gotoAndPlay(5);
  stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
}
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.X) {
  gotoAndPlay(66);
  stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
}
}

function keysDown(event:KeyboardEvent){

 if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
  value = 1;
 }
 if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {  
  value = 2;
 }
 if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {  
  value = 3;
 }

 if (value == 1){
 gotoAndStop(1);
 }
 if (value == 2){
 gotoAndStop(2);
 stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
 }
 if (value == 3){
 gotoAndStop(3);
 stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keysDown);
 }
}
```

Comment: you don't remove your listeners correctly so they still run even when you go to another frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't really need so many listeners, if all you want is to set a value on keydown and go to a frame on key up then you can do the below.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
var value:Number;
stop();

function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case Keyboard.SPACE:
            value = 1;
            break;
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
            value = 2;
            break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
            value = 3;
            break;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
    this.gotoAndStop(value);
}
```

if you wanted to change frames on keydown then you need a regular event listener like an on enterframe to avoid continuously triggering the keyDown event to check for a change in value like:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

var value:Number = 0;
stop();

function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent){
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case Keyboard.SPACE:
            value = 1;
            break;
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
            value = 2;
            break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
            value = 3;
            break;
    }
}

function update(event){
    this.gotoAndStop(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try this tonight and let you know. Also thanks for the code tip.